# template dependent constructor argument lengths

Tags: templates, c++11, constructor, variadic-functions

I try to make a generic, but still efficient multi dimension `Point` class.

What I have is a `Dimensions` `enum`

```
enum Dimension : std::size_t { _2D = 2, _3D = 3 };
```

And a `Point` `class`

```
template <typename T, Dimension D>
class Point : public std::array<T, D>
{
    public:
        T&        at(size_t idx)       { return std::array<T,D>::at(idx); };
        const T&  at(size_t idx) const { return std::array<T,D>::at(idx); };
        Dimension dim()          const { return D; }
        ...
};
```

I would like to create nices constructors so I added (outside my class definition)

```
template <typename T>
Point<T,_2D>::Point(T x, T y)      { at(0) = x; at(1) = y;            }
template <typename T>
Point<T,_3D>::Point(T x, T y, T z) { at(0) = x; at(1) = y; at(2) = z; }
```

But still I cannot use thoses. The compiler tells me only default (empty) and copy constructors are registered.

### Question:

How do I define constructors with arguments list length being dependant on my `Dimension` template ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to accomplish this.  In your case, it might be easiest to use `std::enable_if`:

```
template <typename T, Dimension D>
class Point : public std::array<T, D>
{
    public:
        template <
            Dimension D2=D,
            typename = typename std::enable_if<D2==_2D>::type
        >
        Point(T x,T y);

        template <
            Dimension D2=D,
            typename = typename std::enable_if<D2==_3D>::type
        >
        Point(T x,T y,T z);

        T&        at(size_t idx)       { return std::array<T,D>::at(idx); };
        const T&  at(size_t idx) const { return std::array<T,D>::at(idx); };
        Dimension dim()          const { return D; }
        ...
};
```

Another option would be to break this into multiple classes and use specialization:

```
template <typename T, Dimension D>
class PointBase : public std::array<T, D>
{
    public:
        T&        at(size_t idx)       { return std::array<T,D>::at(idx); };
        const T&  at(size_t idx) const { return std::array<T,D>::at(idx); };
        Dimension dim()          const { return D; }
        ...
};

template <typename T, Dimension D> class Point;

template <typename T>
class Point<T,_2D> : public PointBase<T,_2D> {
    public:
        Point(T x,T y);
};

template <typename T>
class Point<T,_3D> : public PointBase<T,_3D> {
    public:
        Point(T x,T y,T z);
};
```

Comment: IMHO a `Point` class doesn't deserve a hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this because I'm too lazy to write many versions of the same thing:

```
template<class T, Dimension D>
class Point : public std::array<T,D> {

    template<class... Args>
    Point(Args... vs) :
        std::array<T,D>{{vs...}}
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(Args) == D, "wrong number of args");
    }

    ...

};
```